# How to sort collection of mac key

Tags: c++, stl

I need to store a list of devices.
each device has unique mac address.
I thought to store it using a stl map, mac address as key.

I defined struct:

```
struct MacBytes
{
char byte1;
char byte2;
char byte3;
char byte4;
char byte5;
char byte6;

bool operator <(const MacBytes& rhs) const
{
    //add implamention here
}
}
```

Any suggestions to implementation the 'operator <' function (mandatory for stl map), without using many if statments.
Or may suggestion to another representation.

Comment: Note that it is in general much better to make binary operators be non-member functions.  That way if there is a conversion to your class, the comparison will work either way round.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a structure with a bunch of individual `char` fields, use `std::array<char, 6>`.  It's a simpler way to represent the data, and `std::array` already has an `operator<` so you don't need to write your own.

Comment: Or possibly have `struct MacBytes { std::array<unsigned char, 6> bytes; };` then you can write `operator <` as `return lhs.bytes < rhs.bytes;`

Comment: That makes sense if the structure needs to have other fields besides the MAC.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) (or possibly consider implementing `MacBytes` as containing a `std::tuple` directly):

```
operator <(const MacBytes& lhs, const MacBytes& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs.byte1,lhs.byte2,lhs.byte3,lhs.byte4,lhs.byte5,lhs.byte6) <
           std::tie(rhs.byte1,rhs.byte2,rhs.byte3,rhs.byte4,rhs.byte5,rhs.byte6);
}
```

Comment: both std::tie and std::tuple will work only at c++11 and above.

Comment: @Ron:  If you need a solution that works with C++98 or C++03, you really need to say so in the question.  C++11 was released six years ago now.  (You should also mention whether a boost solution is acceptable: boost::tuple has most of the features of std::tuple.) ... and I'm sorry, but std::array is C++11 too.

Comment: Yes you are right. array also need c11 and above I didn't see that. Thanks.